# Notify users when item is back in stock

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Is it possible to let customers enter their email on individual product pages if the stock is 0, and then automatically send them an email when the stock goes above 0 again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not currently possible out of the box with Commerce at time of writing (Sept 2016).

You could write a custom plugin to do it, which would basically keep a table of these people-to-contact, and run a task (or use a controller you trigger by cronjob) -> to send out the emails at such a time the product is re-stocked.

It wouldn't be spectacularly difficult to implement.  Here's a rough sketch:

A form on the site to accept the email addresses -> that form posts to a controller in your plugin - which stores a record of the product, customer email, and date emailed (date emailed is initially null).

You then have a task that periodically runs and checks these records - for each record, if there is no date emailed, check the stock of the product - if greater than zero, send an email and log when it was sent.

Comment: Is this a job you'd be willing to take on?

Comment: In case I wasn't clear and you think I'm a bit entitled, I was suggested that we pay you, of course. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Stian - yep no worries, I understood.  In all honesty, I can't right now - a bit too busy with other things of my own I'm afraid!  I'd be happy to help out in Slack if you're giving it a go - otherwise the slack #jobs channel should find you someone.

Answer (score 2):

I made a plugin to do this thanks to Jeremy's above answer. It's my first Craft plugin BTW.

https://github.com/n-dw/inStockNotifier-Craft